# First site, after content loading

Tags: 7, ajax, performance, nodes

I have a one page template. So, my site is slowly... I use node_load function for all content and want, first css/javascript load, after content load... Is it possible?

Any module or other solution?

Comment: Did you enabled Optimize CSS files and Optimize JavaScript files in "admin/settings/performance". This may help you.

Comment: Thank you but not enough. I installed Boost but still slowly...